# How does one vectorize reinforcement learning environments?

Tags: pytorch, vectorization, reinforcement-learning

I have a Python class that conforms to OpenAI's environment API, but it's written in non-vectorized form i.e. it receives one input action per step and returns one reward per step. How do I vectorize the environment? I haven't been able to find any clear explanation on GitHub.

Comment: I'm curious about what is the use case of having a vectorized environment that accepts an array of actions?

Comment: A single environment wouldn't accept an array of actions. Rather, I'd like to be able to pass in the array of actions and have each one be sent to a separate environment. stable_baselines and baselines both offer `SubprocVecEnv` but these only work in TensorFlow and not even the most recent version.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't thinking in that possibility... I seems insteresting, let see if someone can help!

Comment: This question was also asked on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/ej3v8t/how_to_vectorize_environments/).

Comment: Yes, that was me asking :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a custom class that iterates over an internal tuple of environments while maintaining the basic Gym API. In practice, there will be some differences, because the underlying environments don't terminate on the same timestep. Consequently, it's easier to combine the standard `step` and `reset` functions in
one method called `step`. Here's an example:

```py
class VectorEnv:
    def __init__(self, make_env_fn, n):
        self.envs = tuple(make_env_fn() for _ in range(n))

    # Call this only once at the beginning of training (optional):
    def seed(self, seeds):
        assert len(self.envs) == len(seeds)
        return tuple(env.seed(s) for env, s in zip(self.envs, seeds))

    # Call this only once at the beginning of training:
    def reset(self):
        return tuple(env.reset() for env in self.envs)

    # Call this on every timestep:
    def step(self, actions):
        assert len(self.envs) == len(actions)
        return_values = []
        for env, a in zip(self.envs, actions):
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(a)
            if done:
                observation = env.reset()
            return_values.append((observation, reward, done, info))
        return tuple(return_values)

    # Call this at the end of training:
    def close(self):
        for env in self.envs:
            env.close()
```

Then you can just instantiate it like this:

```py
import gym
make_env_fn = lambda: gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env = VectorEnv(make_env_fn, n=4)
```

You'll have to do a little bookkeeping for your agent to handle the tuple of return values when you call `step`. This is also why I prefer to pass a function `make_env_fn` to `__init__`, because it's easy to add wrappers like `gym.wrappers.Monitor` that track statistics for each environment individually and automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to easily parallelize the environments, instead of running each step serially?

Comment: Also, how should I handle environments concluding after a different number of steps?

Comment: It might be possible to replace the `for` loops with threads, _e.g._ by using the `multiprocessing` module. To be honest, I don't think it would speed things up by much, unless your environment is very expensive to run and justifies the overhead of thread creation. Usually, training the agents is the performance bottleneck (especially if you're using deep neural networks), so it's better to focus optimization on that.

Comment: For your second question, usually you just stop training after a fixed number of timesteps even if some of the environments aren't done. So if you have 10 environments and you want train your agent for a total of 1,000,000 timesteps, you just step the vector environment 100,000 times and then close it -- even if, say, 7/10 of the underlying environments are still in the middle of an episode. I believe [the A3C paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf) did this. Note that `VectorEnv` automatically resets environments if they finish early, so these details are effectively abstracted away.